# Node and NodeJs difference | I have installed Node version's latest using NVM and already installed Nodejs separately but versions are different

Tags: javascript

I have installed the latest version using NVM and NodeJs is already installed.
but the version I have installed using NVM is different from the NodeJs in ubuntu.
what is the difference between Node and NodeJs?

Comment: node is nodejs, there is no difference.  If you need `nvm` to set which version is running, you can `nvm use 14.17.1` for example

Comment: What exactly have you installed and how? Node should be the same as Node.js. But not necessarily - there is also a package in the Debian repositories called `node` which is, if I recall correctly, for ham radio enthusiasts. You might have installed that. If not, then perhaps the Node.js version you installed from one place is older than the other.

Comment: Yeah, right. "IIRC". :)

Comment: @Andy as in "if I recall correctly".

Comment: No, I mean, it's such a niche repo that only someone with knowledge of it would know it existed. "IIRC" as VLAZ twiddles the dials on his ham radio.

Comment: @Andy I know about it because I've tried to install Node.js on Debian-based distros and gotten that one. At the time, Node.js was already popular but you cannot publish a package that has the same name as another. So you had to install `nodejs` from the repositories but then also run a post-fix by doing some symbolic link `node -> nodejs` somewhere, so you could `node index.js`. I thought that was fixed by the repo maintainers by renaming the old `node` package to something else and the Node.js one to `node` but dunno what OP did and how.